# Dependency resolution against local Artifactory takes very long

Tags: artifactory

I have an Artifactory pro (without support) server installed in my local network.

One major use case for this artifactory was to use it as local cache for remote artifacts from e.g. repo1 maven repository or lightbend ivy2 repository. The hope was that I could speedup resolution of dependencies hosted on repo1 when caching them on my local artifactory.

I am pretty sure my development machine is configured correctly to exclusively resolve artifacts against my local artifactory.

However, every once in a while (suspiciously close to the interval configured as `Metadata Retrieval Cache Period (Sec)` in the *Advanced* Tab of the remote repository settings), the resolution of dependencies originally hosted on maven repo 1 takes far longer then usual.

I suspect that at these times artifactory refreshes artifact meta data (*pom, ivy.xml*) of remote artifacts. But this takes far longer than I would expect, assuming that a simple pom or ivy download should not take several seconds but rather a few milli seconds.

I am currently requesting root access to the server for attempting a *tcpdump* from OPs which may take time...

**So my question is**

Has anyone an idea what actually might happen that takes several seconds per dependency of a remote repository to refresh meta data files or am I looking in the wrong direction?

**Update**

My Artifactory version is

**Artifactory Professional 5.1.3 rev 50019**

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue but with npm repo's where the meta data re-calculation was taking quite sometime and eventually we came to know that it was a bug in artifactory and was resolved in version 6.1.0. Worth checking the artifactory jira's for any such bugs. Hope so this helps!
[Artifactory Jira Link](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-15269)